# Hide labels in 3d Doughnut chart of fusion charts for angular

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

Hi all i am using fusion charts for 3d doughnut chart in angular application.

please let me know how to hide labels in 3d doughnut chart.
(I want to hide values around 3d doughnut chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the labels please set showLabels as 0 & to hide the values set showValues as 0, both of these attributes need to be applied at the chart object level, here is a demo

```
chart :{
showLabels:0,
showValues:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the values you need to use :

```
chart :{
showLabels:0,
showValues:0
}
```

Here is the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/qhcynrfz/